# ValueError: TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am getting same error when i use following CNN code. I could not understand the answers for similar problem. I am trying to run the project on following link and i am getting error particulary in the following part of code. https://www.kaggle.com/michalbrezk/x-ray-pneumonia-cnn-tensorflow-2-0-keras-94

Is this a version issue i think but which one is proper for this error?

```
history = model.fit(
          datagen.flow(X_train,y_train, batch_size=4), 
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
          epochs = 100, verbose = 1, 
          callbacks=[callback], 
          class_weight={0:6.0, 1:0.5})
```

ValueError: TypeError: len() of unsized object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem, it is related the version of tools.
I created a environment with python 3.6 and tensorflow 2.3